# How do I add a border header of a link on my navigation bar while removing the div's border?

Tags: html, css, header, border, navbar

This is what it looks like at the moment:
I want to remove the gray border under the 'active' class element (i.e. the Home in this picture), while having the orange thicker bottom-border replace it. How do I go about doing that?

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

div.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px;
}

div.header a.text {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

div.header a.text:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

div.header a.text.active {
    color: #ff5e00;
    border-bottom: solid #ff5e00;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ant Arni's Crappy Site!</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=header>
            <a href=# class="text active">Home</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Members</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Handbook</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Apply</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Staff</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `after` and remove border-bottom from `.active` class

```
div.header a.text.active {
    position: relative;
}

div.header a.text.active::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ff5e00;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: It works thank you! But why? Is the "after element" simply adding another element 'on top' of my element, but you are displacing it by putting it underneath and making a new shape of height 3px?

Comment: Yes. after and before ( https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/:after ) adds new element. I added position: relative to a.text.active - that gives me the possibility to place "after element"  whereever I want using position absolute. left:0 AND right: 0 means that this element will be as wide as parent with position relative

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way. Add to active link:

```
margin: 0 0 -2px;
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

div.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px;
}

div.header a.text {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

div.header a.text:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

div.header a.text.active {
    color: #ff5e00;
    border-bottom: solid #ff5e00;
    margin: 0 0 -2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ant Arni's Crappy Site!</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=header>
            <a href=# class="text active">Home</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Members</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Handbook</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Apply</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Staff</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:psuedo` elemnt `:after`instead of direct if you want costum position.

here the snippet :

```css
div.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px;
}

div.header a.text {
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

div.header a.text:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

div.header a.text.active {
    color: #ff5e00;
 }
 
 div.header a.text.active:after{
       content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    border-bottom: solid #ff5e00;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class=header>
            <a href=# class="text active">Home</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Members</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Handbook</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Apply</a>
            <a href=# class=text>Staff</a>
        </div>
```